# Function specifier

Tags: c++

virtual and inline are function specifier.

They can appear before function only.{as per my understanding}.

Then,In following code what is virtual?

```
class Base
{
//
};

class Derived :virtual public Base
{
};
```

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.9 This will help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is about the wording in the standard, then you must have misunderstood it. It is true that the list of various function specifiers includes the keyword `virtual` as one possible function specifier. However, it doesn't work in other direction: the keyword `virtual` is not restricted to being the function specifier only. It has other use(s). You have found an example of that - it can be used to declare virtual base classes.

Comment: Thanks Andrey I was confused with wordings in standard only.
It was not about "Virtual Inheritance".

Answer (score 5):

This is [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).

Answer (score 2):

> $10.1/4- "A base class specifier that
>   contains the keyword virtual,
>   specifies a virtual base class. For
>   each distinct occurrence of a
>   nonvirtual base class in the class
>   lattice of the most derived class, the
>   most derived object (1.8) shall
>   contain a corresponding distinct base
>   class subobject of that type. **For each
>   distinct base class that is specified
>   virtual, the most derived object shall
>   contain a single base class subobject
>   of that type."**

So given the hierarchy

```
struct A{};
struct B : virtual A{};
struct C : virtual A{};
struct D : B, C{};

D d;
```

A 'd' object has only one 'A' subobject i.e. the constructor of 'A' is called only once, and that too before any other constructor is run.

> $12.6.2/5 - "Initialization shall
>   proceed in the following order:
>
> —
>   **First, and only for the constructor of
>   the most derived class as described
>   below, virtual base classes shallbe
>   initialized in the order they appear
>   on a depth-first left-to-right
>   traversal of the directed acyclic
>   graph of base classes, where
>   “left-to-right” is the order of
>   appearance of the base class names in
>   the derived class base-specifier-list.**
>
> — Then, direct base classes shall be
>   initialized in declaration order as
>   they appear in the base-specifier-list
>   (regardless of the order of the
>   mem-initializers).
>
> — Then, nonstatic
>   data members shall be initialized in
>   the order they were declared in the
>   class definition (again regardless of
>   the order of the mem-initializers).
>
> —
>   Finally, the body of the constructor
>   is executed. [Note: the declaration
>   order is mandated to ensure that base
>   and member subobjects are destroyed in
>   the reverse order of initialization. ]

Comment: Then in case of virtual is what??
A function specifier !! Definitely not.

Comment: @Sudhendu Sharma: Virtual has different meanings in different contexts. As a virtual specifier on class member functions, it is a mechanism to support dynamic binding. It basically represents a behavior that the derived class may override. When used as a base class specifier, it indicates what I have described in my post

Answer (score 1):

It is virtual inheritance, look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) for an explanation.

The common usage is, if you have a class A inheriting from 2 classes B and C, which in turn inherit from the same ancestor D. This is problematic with normal inheritance, since A would contain two instances of D, so which one should be used. Using virtual inheritance, e.g. C inheriting virtual from D, the address of the D instance in the C-part of A is found in the vmt, so it can point to the same instance that the B-part is using

Answer (score 0):

[virtual inheritence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) its used to specify how inheritence works when there is multiple inheritence. essentially it allows you to have 'diamond' inhertitence graphs as opposed to non virtual which would give you a tree, with multiple bases clases at the leaves (raising potenetial ambiguity problems).